# Changing keyboard language from English to Greek

Tags: internet-explorer

I have an US bought laptop with Windows 7 and IE9 installed.

I want to occasionally change the keyboard to write in Greek. I added Greek to the preferred languages but it still does not write Greek.

When I use Google Chrome in the same laptop I can easily switch. Only IE has that problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you do it in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to download the [Greek language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1944) for IE9, available from Microsoft, in order to be able to use another language in Internet Explorer. It's the one named "`IE9-Windows6.1-LanguagePack-x86-ell.msu`".